# scott account locked in SQL Plus

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

When I am trying to logging to Oracle Sql plus by entering  'scott' as username and 'tiger' as password, it shows 'the account is locked'. How to unlock 'scott' account. The screen shot of SQL Plus CLI is given below.

[image: The screen shot is given below]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Login in to your DB with user `SYS`

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 25 15:13:25 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
```

then issue

```
alter user scott account unlock;
```

Then you will be able to login as scott.

```
conn scott/tiger
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be coming from the good old days of Oracle 8 :) It was finally acknowledged that a non-trivial amount of **production** DB instances were running with that account and it's default password still in it's initial setup form which is why Oracle has eventually patched that security hole.

To your specific question - [here's a link](http://www.tiplib.com/103/unlock-oracle-user-account) (first hit in `Google` search, actually) that explain it.

**Edit**: Pasting the answer from the link into here for your convenience:

> Here's how to lock or unlock Oracle database user accounts.
>
> SQL> ALTER USER username ACCOUNT LOCK;
>
> SQL> ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

Comment: thanks for help.. i am new to Oracle. i am still not logged to any account in sqlplus. i think it must be logged in to perform the specified command. So how to loggin..

Comment: @yephlck this is not working for me kindly guide, what i get after this is "not connected to oracle".

Comment: You have to be connected to a DB in order to be able to administer it. Use your administrator credentials to log-in into DB first, then you can perform the task you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SQL command to change the password and unlock an account at the same time:

```
ALTER USERNAME  IDENTIFIED BY Password ACCOUNT UNLOCK
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Connect to a database by using below command:

```
SQL> conn /as sysdba
```

2) Now try to unlock the user :

```
SQL > alter user scott account unlock;
```

For Example :

```
SQL> conn /as sysdba
Connected.

SQL > alter user scott account unlock;
User altered.
```

The user scott is unlock now

Answer (score 0):

You can use below steps to account unlock

SQL> select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS from dba_users where username='SCOTT';

USERNAME                       ACCOUNT_STATUS

---

SCOTT                       LOCKED

SQL> alter user SCOTT account unlock;

User altered.

SQL> select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS from dba_users where username='SCOTT';

USERNAME                       ACCOUNT_STATUS

---

SCOTT                       OPEN

SQL> conn SCOTT/SCOTT
Connected.
SQL>

Answer (score 0):

1.copy oracle path
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\scott.sql

2.Connect with sys as sysdba

3.Then paste in prompt->
@C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\scott.sql

4.then connect with System user.

5.alter user scott account unlock;

6.alter user scott identified by tiger;